# Wordpress pagination with WP_Query not working

Tags: wordpress

This is my code.

```
 <?php
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $next_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'articles',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => 3, // post per page
                    'paged' => $paged,
                );
                $next_the_query = new WP_Query($next_args);
                if ($next_the_query->have_posts()) :
                ?>

                    <?php while ($next_the_query->have_posts()) : $next_the_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <div class="pagination">
                    <?php
                    $total_pages = $next_the_query->max_num_pages;

                    if ($total_pages > 1){
                
                        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
                
                        echo paginate_links(array(
                            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                            'format' => '/page/%#%',
                            'current' => $current_page,
                            'total' => $total_pages,
                            'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
                            'next_text'    => __('next »'),
                        ));
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>

                <?php endif; ?>
```

I get links like this, **1 2 3 4 next »**.

But unfortunately when I click a link **I get 404 not found error**

This is my site original link,

**[www.mysite.com/blog/](http://www.mysite.com/blog/)**

and getting 404 for **[www.mysite.com/blog/page/2](http://www.mysite.com/blog/page/2)** link

Comment: Is the link correct? Maybe you need to update your permalink settings (just save it again)

Comment: @Cray did and still get same 404 :'(

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the original link and one of the links that gets 404.

Comment: @O.Jones updated the question as requested

Comment: Could you also post your .htaccess file or at least the portion handling WP rewrites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found an answer and adding it here for future users,

I had to change query parameter from **'paged'** to **'page'**.

```
<?php
    $page = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    $next_args = array(
         'post_type' => 'articles',
         'post_status' => 'publish',
         'posts_per_page' => 3, // post per page
         'paged' => $page,
    );
```

Here also I changed **'paged'** to **'page'**. And changed format like `'format' => '?page=%#%',` And also kept **'base'** option of **paginate_links** array as default

```
$current_page = max(1, get_query_var('page'));

echo paginate_links(array(
    'format' => '?page=%#%',
    'current' => $current_page,
    'total' => $total_pages,
    'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
    'next_text'    => __('next »'),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Log in to WordPress as the administrator
Under Dashboard, click Settings, and then click Permalinks. The Permalink Settings page appears.
Under Common Settings, select the permalink structure that you want to use for your pages and posts.

more information: https://wordpress.org/support/article/settings-permalinks-screen/

Comment: i have selected `Post name -> https://www.example.com/sample-post/` is there any way i can go with it?